# How can I check if any items in an array are substrings in one of the columns in my table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not sure how to go about this:

I have a column named `description` in my database. I have a list of keywords. I want to select the rows where the description contains at least one of the strings in my list.

The list is of strings, and the description is of type TEXT.

I just don't want to do a hideous brute force method of doing multiple LIKEs (because my list is currently 50 elements).

Comment: Is your array a table or is an input to your query parser ?

Comment: My array is an input to query parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a SQL query like this (just I write it on the fly):

```
WITH tags(tag) AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('tag1'),('tag2'),('tag3'),('tag4')) AS tags(tag))
SELECT DISTINCT description
FROM tbl
WHERE (description LIKE '%' || tag || '%');
```

That you can insert your list instead of `('tag1'),('tag2'),('tag3'),('tag4')`. That you need something like `"(" + replace(yorTagString, ",", "),(") + ")"`.

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e6460/20)

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! Currently getting this error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown + text[] for the line "where experience like '%'+ arr +'%'"

Comment: try `'%' || arr || '%` instead of `CONCAT('%', arr, '%')`

Comment: @vkp As you said I use `||` ;). and I finally finished it.